# Converting graph object into text file

Tags: r, dataframe, graph

I have a data frame which contains two graphs (nodes and edges).
Node `node` contains graph name `object`, node ID `id` and node attribute `func`.
Edge `edge` contains graph name `object`, connection of two nodes `"from" and "to"` and its attributes `func`. `object` is an identifier of different graphs.

```
## Prepare data frame
node <- data.frame(object=c("2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889"), id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), func=c(6,18,18,3,19,18,11,6,18,19,18,18,18,20))

edge <- data.frame(object=c("2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","2-1887","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889","4-1889"), from=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,1,2,2,3,4,5,6), to=c(2,3,4,6,6,6,7,2,3,4,4,5,6,7), func=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1))
```

I coded some scripts which converts `data.frame` to `graph` format for an analysis purpose.

```
## Convert data frame into list by object name
n <- node %>% group_by(object) %>% group_map(~.x) %>% setNames(unique(sort(node$object)))
e <- edge %>% group_by(object) %>% group_map(~.x) %>% setNames(unique(sort(edge$object)))

## Convert node and edge lists into graphs
g <- mapply(function(x,y) {tbl_graph(x,y,directed=FALSE)},n,e)
```

On the other hand, now I also need another format of graphs which should be exported in`.txt` file:

```
t # 0
v 0 6
v 1 18
v 2 18
v 3 3
v 4 19
v 5 18
v 6 11
e 0 1 1
e 1 2 1
e 2 3 2
e 2 5 2
e 3 5 2
e 4 5 2
e 5 6 1

t # 1
v 0 6
v 1 18
v 2 19
v 3 18
v 4 18
v 5 18
v 6 20
e 0 1 1
e 1 2 2
e 1 3 2
e 2 3 2
e 3 4 1
e 4 5 1
e 5 6 1
```

In this format, `t #` indicates graph ID starting from zero, `v` indicates vertex ID which also start from zero, not one and its attribuets `(func)`, and `e` indicates edge connection `("from" and "to")` and its attributes `(func)` in each column.
I appreciate your idea to convert the original data frame into this text format. We can start either a set of data frame (`node` and `edge`), a set of a tibble format (`n` and `e`) or a tbl_graph format (`g`).

As this format does not accept graph ID as an identifier but accept sequential number starting from zero, I also need an equivalent table which indicates correspondence between graph ID and sequential ID `t`. This table is not necessarily exported in `.txt` file but in `data.frame`.

```
t object
0 2-1887
1 4-1889
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I could make it using the following scripts:

```
for (i in 1:length(g$graph)) {
  
  ## Add header
  write.table(paste0("t # ",i-1), "test.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep=" ")

  #### Nodes
  ## Nodes
  g$graph[[i]] %>% activate(nodes) %>% mutate(v="v") %>% data.frame() %>% select(v, id, func) %>%
    write.table(., "test.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep=" ")
    
  ## Write edges
  g$graph[[i]] %>% activate(edges) %>% mutate(e="e") %>% data.frame() %>% select(e, from, to, connect) %>%
    write.table(., "test.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep=" ")
  
  ## Line break
  write.table("", "test.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, sep="\n")

}
```

Equivalent table:

```
eq <- data.frame(t = c(0:(length(g$graph)-1)), object = names(g$graph))
```